# MinGW relocation table

Tags: mingw, ld, pic

I try to enable ALSR on PE exeuctable compiled in 8 64 MinGW environment. Options Wl,--dynamicbase and Wl,--pic-executable don't help. There is no relocation table in produced executable. I also tried option -Wl,--emit-relocs, but it didn't help. Is there a way to force MinGW's ld to leave relocation table in executable? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Passing `-Wl,--dynamicbase,--export-all-symbols` works, but it's an awful hack. It's sad that this isn't fixed in MinGW-w64 yet.